# how should i store files for iis web root on windows servers in nlb configuration?

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems, network-share, nlb

I have multiple windows virtual machines in a network load balanced environment.  They each have a local disk (C: drive) that has the files for delivering our website (inetpub/wwwroot).  The problem is that any change I need to make to a web page needs to be updated on every machine.  Should I be using another method for file storage?  Ideally I'd like to move away from having to remote desktop onto every machine when I need to be an update.

What is the ideal method for file storage when running multiple machines in a NLB environment and why?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Continous Integration / Continous Delivery (CI/CD). Usually you would have a webhook from your repository software telling the servers to pull the newest version of the website.

A different way would be to use a shared filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just implement DFS/DFS-R between your nodes then move your inetpub there, then any change to one machine is replicated to all. I was going to suggest just moving it to a NAS-type share but that introduces a single-point-of-failure whereas DFS/DFS-R shouldn't.